# Как скопировать файл в буфер обмена на питоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, импорт

Ребят напишете код, есть файл cmd, хочу сделать кнопку которая будет его копировать в буфер

```
tk = Tk()                                                                       
tk.title("CMD")                                            
tk.geometry("500x450")                                                          
tk.image = PhotoImage(file="image/cmd")       
screen1 = Label(tk, image=tk.image)                                             
screen1.grid(row=0, column=0)                                                   
tk.resizable(width=False, height=False)                                                                    
bl = Button(tk,text = "скопировать", command = sss)                                     
bl.place(x=200,y=300, width=200, height=50) 
def sss():
```

если бы был текст, я бы побочному написал, но как именно файл прикрепить ?

Comment: shutil.copyfile(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True) https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

Comment: Я не понимаю как использовать srs что туда записывать ?

Comment: src и dst — это объекты, подобные путям, или имена путей, заданные в виде строк.